# FXT-009 Wavecom GSM Modem access via Serial Port using Java

Tags: java, serial-port, at-command

I am trying to access and send SMS through Wavecom's FXT-009 using Serial Port in Java. I have tried retrieving input and outstreams from the SerialPort object but when I write "AT" commands to the outputstream thread I don't get any response on the inputstream thread.

The modem and commands work perfectly fine in the eclipse based Wavecom IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a thread with the SerialPortEventListener worked for me

```
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
                break;
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
                StringBuffer readBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                int c;
                try{

                    while ((c=inputStream.read()) != 10){
                        if(c!=13 && c != 1){
                            readBuffer.append((char) c);
                        }
                    }
                    String scannedInput = readBuffer.toString();

                        /*
                    DO YOUR THING HERE     
                        */  

                } catch (IOException e) {}

                break;
        }
}
```